# Jenkins Pipeline Custom Class - inconsistent handling of toString() method

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline script in which I have created a custom class to represent an AWS AMI. This class extends java.lang.Object and overrides java.lang.Object.toString(). The obvious intention being that I could refer to the object directly when creating strings and get a useful string representing the object.

Unfortunately, jenkins-pipeline doesn't quite see it that way. It is happy to respect requests for the toString() method directly, but without toString, my println/echo steps are silently dropped or produce inconsistent output.

See the snippet below for what I am talking about, and how a different class, e.g. Map works precisely as intended.

Additionally, the code works **perfectly** in the Jenkins script console. But in a jenkins-pipeline job, even with Sandbox disabled; it does not.

```
public class Ami implements Serializable {
  private String nodetype
  private String id
  private String created
  private boolean related
  private boolean rebuild

  Ami(
    String nodetype,
    String id       = 'None',
    String created  = 'None',
    boolean related = false,
    boolean rebuild = false
  ) {
    this.nodetype = nodetype
    this.id       = id
    this.created  = created
    this.related  = related
    this.rebuild  = rebuild
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    this.nodetype + '/' + this.id
  }
}

Ami newami = new Ami('foo')
println("Concat toString: " + newami.toString())
println("Concat normal: " + newami)
println("Templated toString: ${newami.toString()}")
println("Templated normal: ${newami}")

Map testmap = [:]
testmap = [foo: "bar", snizz: 'snooch']
println("Concat toString: " + testmap.toString())
println("Concat normal: " + testmap)
println("Templated toString: ${testmap.toString()}")
println("Templated normal: ${testmap}")
```

Script Console Output (as expected):

```
Concat toString: foo/None
Concat normal: foo/None
Templated toString: foo/None
Templated normal: foo/None
Concat toString: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
Concat normal: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
Templated toString: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
Templated normal: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
```

Jenkins Pipeline (Sandbox Disabled) Output (completely unexpected):

```
[Pipeline] echo
Concat toString: foo/None
[Pipeline] echo
foo/None
[Pipeline] echo
Templated toString: foo/None
[Pipeline] echo
Concat toString: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
[Pipeline] echo
Concat normal: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
[Pipeline] echo
Templated toString: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
[Pipeline] echo
Templated normal: [foo:bar, snizz:snooch]
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong? could you also provide pipeline script?

Comment: @daggett What is wrong is that the output from the pipeline job fails to print "Concat normal: foo/None" instead just printing "foo/None", and the line "Templated normal: foo/None" is completely skipped, with no output. When run from the script console, these lines print normally.

The pipeline script is the first block. First a class is defined, then an object is instantiated using the class, and then 8 println steps demonstrate the problems printing the object without explicitly calling toString(), an it not being a problem for native classes such as Map.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, lines without explicit ".toString()" are completely ignored. Still finding a solution